# Did not get total from second input fields?

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to javascript writing some code by myself using DOM technique. My First block of code work properly and it gives me sum to first two input fields but i didn't get sum when i entered values of 2nd block of code. here is my code

```
<body>
        <script language ="javascript">
                function Calculate(){

                    var pricee = document.getElementById('price').value;
                    var qtyy = document.getElementById('qty').value;
                    var sum = pricee * qtyy;
                    document.getElementById('total').value = sum;

                    var newprice = document.getElementById('price2').value;
                    var newqty = document.getElementById('qty2').value;
                    var sum2 = newprice * newqty;
                    document.getElementById('total2').value = sum2;
                }
            </script>


    <form>
       Product Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="productName">
       <br>
       Product Price: <input type="text" id="price" name="productPrice">
       <br>
       Product Qty: <input type="text" id="qty" name="productQty" type="text" id="total" name="producttotal"
       onChange="Calculate()">
       <br>
       Total: <input type="text" id="total" name="producttotal">

       <hr>

       Product Name: <input type="text" id="name2" name="productName">
       <br>
       Product Price: <input type="text" id="price2" name="productPrice">
       <br>
       Product Qty: <input type="text" id="qty2" name="productQty" type="text" id="total" name="producttotal"
       onChange="Calculate()">
       <br>
       Total: <input type="text" id="total2" name="producttotal">



    </form>
```

Comment: Is there any reason for **sum** to be a **product**?... Besides, you have two inputes with the same ID, being the product qty inputs. change those to unique IDs.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand ?

Comment: ID's are different for both inputs brioshje as 'price' 'qty' and 'price2' and 'qty2'

Comment: Are you sure? `<input type="text" id="qty" name="productQty" type="text" id="total" name="producttotal"
       onChange="Calculate()">` :)

Comment: Thanks Brioshje.. for the help.. works

Comment: You should take care of additional points, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues with your code:

1. Your input types are **text**, so their value is treated as **text**. You should rather convert those values to **numbers** instead before doing mathematicals operations on them.
2. Your "Qty" inputs have multiple `id` and `name` and `type`. It's probably a copy-paste error.

To fix point 1, you can add a cast to number using the unary operator (+) like this:

```
function Calculate(){
  var pricee = +document.getElementById('price').value;
  var qtyy = +document.getElementById('qty').value;
  var sum = pricee * qtyy;
  document.getElementById('total').value = sum;

  var newprice = +document.getElementById('price2').value;
  var newqty = +document.getElementById('qty2').value;
  var sum2 = newprice * newqty;
  document.getElementById('total2').value = sum2;
}
```

To fix point 2, you just need to remove extra tags from your inputs:

First one:

```
Product Qty: <input type="text" id="qty" name="productQty" type="text" id="total" name="producttotal"
       onChange="Calculate()">
```

should become this:

```
Product Qty: <input type="text" id="qty" name="productQty" onChange="Calculate()">
```

And second one should follow the same rule.
Also, you should add the `onChange` event on every input concerning the calculation.

Full working code:

HTML:

```
Product Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="productName">
       <br>
       Product Price: <input type="text" id="price" onChange="Calculate()" name="productPrice">
       <br>
       Product Qty: <input type="text" id="qty" name="productQty" onChange="Calculate()">
       <br>
       Total: <input type="text" id="total" name="producttotal">

       <hr>

       Product Name: <input type="text" id="name2" name="productName">
       <br>
       Product Price: <input type="text" id="price2" onChange="Calculate()" name="productPrice">
       <br>
       Product Qty: <input type="text" id="qty2" onChange="Calculate()" name="productQty"
       onChange="Calculate()">
       <br>
       Total: <input type="text" id="total2" name="producttotal">
```

Javascript:

```
function Calculate(){
  var pricee = +document.getElementById('price').value;
  var qtyy = +document.getElementById('qty').value;
  var sum = pricee * qtyy;
  document.getElementById('total').value = sum;

  var newprice = +document.getElementById('price2').value;
  var newqty = +document.getElementById('qty2').value;
  var sum2 = newprice * newqty;
  document.getElementById('total2').value = sum2;
}
```

Working fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/cjxs7pLo/1/

As a side (irrelevant) note, you're defining a variable called `sum` whose value is the **product** of two values. This is not relevant in any way for the code, but its name is misleading and should be fixed, since other people reading your code may think it's a sum, but it's **not** a sum.

Comment: thanks for the help bro.. works
unfortunately i didn't cast my vote coz i am having less then 15 reputation but will push you up whenever i reached 15

Comment: you're welcome. feel free to accept the answer above to close the post.